# Find the radius of convergence of two series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to tell the convergence-radius of the following series:

1. $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n^5x^n$
   Here I thought about using Euler and I get $\lim \frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^5} = 1$ So the convergence-radius is $1$?
   Instead I could have used the Cauchy-Hadamard and I would get:
   $r = \frac{1}{\limsup (\sqrt[n](|n^5|)}$ - what now?
2. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x+1)^n\frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn^2}$
   What exactly should I do here?

Comment: For (1), use that $\sqrt[n]{n^5} = \left(\sqrt[n]{n}\right)^5$ and that $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$\bullet\;\;\;\;\sqrt[n]{n^5}=n^{5/n}=\left(\sqrt[n]n\right)^5\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1^5=1$$

$$\bullet\;\;\;\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\;\frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}(n+1)^2}\cdot\frac{2^nn^2}{(x+1)^n}\;\right|=\frac12\,|x+1|\frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12|x+1|<1\iff$$

$$\iff |x+1|<2\iff -3<x<1$$

Answer (score 1):

The ratio test is sufficient, in these cases.

(1) Set $a_n=n^5x^n$. Then

$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|
 =\lim_n\to\infty \frac{(n+1)^5\,|x|}{n^5}=|x|
$$

so the series converges for $|x|<1$ and diverges for $|x|>1$.

(2) Set $y=x+1$ and $a_n=\frac{(-1)^ny^n}{2^nn^2}$; then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{n}n^2}{2^{n+1} (n+1)^2}|y|=\frac{|y|}{2}.
$$
Therefore the series converges for $|y|<2$ and diverges for $|y|>2$.